# Why is the LinkedIn API's 'picture-urls::(original)' field no longer returning values?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been importing photos with the `picture-urls::(original)` field for years but since 2018/2/26 about half of profiles have not been returning this field and since 2018/3/1 none of them have been returning it. The `picture-url` field is not a usable substitute since the photos are too small.

The field is still documented as part of the [basic profile](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile). Several others are having this problem too:

1. [Linked in Omniauth photo_urls or picture-urls::(original) not being returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050669/linked-in-omniauth-photo-urls-or-picture-urlsoriginal-not-being-returned)
2. [LinkedIn not picking up og:image from wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071145/linkedin-not-picking-up-ogimage-from-wordpress)

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm experiencing the opposite. I get the picture-urls but not the picture-url. In other words, I'm NOT getting the smaller and processed version but I do get the larger, original one. This started to happen recently for me too.

Comment: No, nothing yet. Still broken on my production site. That's so odd that you're having the opposite problem. No idea what to make of that.

Comment: I'm getting 403 errors with the picture urls I'm getting

Comment: @andreyrd just curious, are you storing URLs and fetching them later, or are they 403ing as soon as you get them?

Comment: Never mind on that one, I believe the URLs changed format (?) and started including some characters that my code now tried to escape. Fixed that on my end. But yes, I'm storing them, but only for the length of the session.

Comment: We also have the same requirement (larger photos) and have been leveraging the `picture-urls::(original)` field. I can confirm the same experience with pictures sometimes coming back intermittently, then not coming back at all. This is a pretty huge issue for us since we basically rely on these images to be there and can't rely on the small pictures for larger badges.

Comment: Having the same issue. Wondering if this has something to do with the GDPR changes they're doing? I can't find a support email or anything to ask them though. :(

Comment: We've been seeing issue with the pictures for a few weeks. We just had a user return without a `public-profile-url` for the first time too...

Comment: Any update on this one? We're also finding that the `public-profile-url` (linkedin url) has been missing here and there as well

Comment: It appears to have started working again for me - had the same problem for over a month and tried again today and its finally returns the picture-urls field and gives me a large image

Answer (score 1):

The development of the v2 of the API is at a very advanced state and eventually v1 will lose all support in a more or less organized manner.

Use v2 with a projection to get the urn to the source image `pictureInfo(cropInfo,croppedImage,hidden,masterImage)`

And from then get the image. I doubt a fix will come for something that is going to get deprecated.