# Intermittently receiving 401 unauthorized for LinkedIn API using OAuth 1.0a

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api

Our application has begun receiving "(401): [unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumerKey: XXXXXXX" error messages from LinkedIn. The errors started on 2/16/18. We have had no issues previously, nor have we changed any code related to LinkedIn authorization.

We're running RoR 5 with gems [linkedin](https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin) and [omniauth-linkedin](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin) which authenticates using OAuth 1.0a.

[We've followed this tutorial from the omniauth-linkedin gem](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin#using-it-with-the-linkedin-gem)

[Here's a visual of the error frequency from the past 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr0Bg.png)

I've been trying to debug this issue locally. We found that it is only for new users who have not given our application access to their profile, or returning (deleted) users who have revoked access.

Steps to replicate: If I delete my account through our application, revoke access for the application from my LinkedIn profile, then try to create a new profile in my application, logging in with my LinkedIn profile, it throws a 401 unauthorized error. From around 11am - 3:15pm, I was able to replicate the issue, but unable to find a fix. Around 3:20pm, the authentication started working again, following the exact same steps to replicate.

Has anyone else experienced this with LinkedIn before?

It should be noted that we're also experiencing issues with the LinkedIn API pulling back profile_urls, which already has a [StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074069/why-is-the-linkedin-apis-picture-urlsoriginal-field-no-longer-returning-v) open.

Edit:

Notes about steps to replicate: A user accesses the application for the first time and requests to login with LinkedIn. The user grants our application access. Intermittently, LinkedIn responds with 401 unauthorized. If the user revokes permissions, when the user tries to login the next time, the application correctly asks for permission again, and once granted by the user, LinkedIn is still intermittently returning 401 unauthorized.

The case when the user denies permisson to use their LinkedIn profile is handled correctly.

Comment: I never used LinkedIn APIs, but this is a problem for many of them =) If someone (a) did not grant you permissions or (b) revoked access, you should catch the error, check the reason and (a) insist and ask again (b) refresh user token

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should clarify. This happens when a user is new for the first time, actually grants our application permissions, and then we receive the 401. This doesn't occur when the user denies permisson to use their LinkedIn profile. If the user revokes permissions, it correctly asks for permission again, and once granted, still sends a 401. I'll update the original post as well.